# Converting a type to an array

Tags: c#, wsdl

I am creating a parser for Web Services. I am in a road block.

I have an XML document which is

```
<AdvisorName>
  <PersonNameTitle>String[]</PersonNameTitle>
  <PersonGivenName>String[]</PersonGivenName>
  <PersonFamilyName>String</PersonFamilyName>
  <PersonNameSuffix>String[]</PersonNameSuffix>
  <PersonRequestedName>String</PersonRequestedName>
</AdvisorName>
```

My code is

```
foreach (XElement childNodeprop in childNodesPropLst)
{
    XElement childElement = childNodeprop.Element(prop.Name);

    if (childElement != null)
    {
        // Error happens at next line:
        prop.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(childElement.Value, prop.PropertyType), 
            null);

        break;
    }
}
```

As you had seen that the XML whose return type is an array it can't convert this.

Full Code is attached here with

```
foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.SetProperty))
{
    if (!prop.Name.Equals("ExtensionData"))
    { 
        if (prop.PropertyType.IsPrimitive())
        {
            var childNodesPropLst = doc.Descendants(propertyName);
            foreach (XElement childNodeprop in childNodesPropLst)
            {
                XElement childElement = childNodeprop.Element(prop.Name);
                if (childElement != null)
                {
                    prop.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(childElement.Value, prop.PropertyType), null);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just out of curiosity, have you looked into xml serialization? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Also, you aren't showing the full code (i.e. where `prop1` is instantiated). Can you include that as well?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I concur with Rufus that custom XML deserialization probably isn't necessary if using .NET's built-in XML serialization ([Introducing XML Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh.aspx)), but if you must, you can try using TypeConverters like:

```
var type = //get type
TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type).ConvertFrom(stringSerialization);
```

Comment: I can't do an serialization hence i am writing a parser. The problem is that if PropertyType is an array then how do we set the value.

Answer (score 0):

I think i have worked up on it what i did was

```
if (prop.PropertyType.IsArray )
                        {

                            ArrayList arrLst = new ArrayList();

                            var arrayElements = childNodeprop.Elements(prop.Name);

                            foreach(XElement element in arrayElements )
                            {
                                arrLst.Add(element.Value);
                            }
                            var  BaseElementType= prop.PropertyType.GetElementType();
                            prop.SetValue(obj, arrLst.ToArray(BaseElementType), null);


                        }
and it works..
```